# Instantiate CDI beans dynamically or inject in non-cdi-beans

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, weld

I'm new to CDI and hope someone can help me.

Well, let me explain problem:
I implemented a main bean which is called by JSF EL. This bean handles a list of objects. Just imagine something like `List<Car>`.
These car objects are constructed in the @PostMethod method of the main bean.
Additionally I have some service classes e.g. CarServices which provides something like `public static List<Car> getCarsOfBrand(Session session, Brand brand)`.
Inside the service classes the Hibernate session is used to run a query and return the deserved list.
So, well... I wanted to get rid of passing the session object. So my plan was to inject it.
I created a SessionScoped bean "PersistenceUnit" (may be that name is already preallocated, sorry for that...) with a method `public Session getCurrentSession()`.
I simply want to inject this bean in all my Service classes to just call something like `getCarsOfBrand(Brand brand)`.
The problem is, that I can't inject CDI beans to non-beans. (Car is currently just a POJO).
I tried to handle this by declaring car to an CDI bean, too, by adding a @SessionScoped.
But the next problem was, that the Car objects were instantiated by me and not by the Container.
I tried something like

```
@Produces
public Car createCar() {
     return new Car();
}
```

But that was also not successful: I thought this annotated method returns a proxy of car. But nothing happened. An injected field inside of car was still null and its @PostConstruct method was also never called.

So can you help me? What is the correct approach for injecting the current context (the session) to my service classes?

Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a solution by myself! :-)

I annotate the service classes as @ApplicationScoped and inject whatever I need.
The Car-Class uses the service but is no bean itself.
For this I use DeltaSpike for the Injection when I instatiate the object:

```
public Car() {
  BeanProvider.injectFields(this);
}
```

Hope I could help someone in the future! :-)

Comment: You're leaking the 'this' reference in a constructor. Don't. Many subtle horrible things may happen. And putting CDI bean instances as attributes of an non CDI managed bean will cause trouble, memory leaks comes to mind as a first. Said that, there might be a fundamental design flaw here. In the other hand, If Car should be a CDI bean, just use constructor injection.